# how to add a class numbered from 4 onwards

Tags: jquery, each, counter

I have added classes to all of my elements but I want the classes to start from the number 4(first class is .cc_content_4 and the next .cc_content_5 and so on) so I tried to change the number the counter is set to. It didn't work
Any ideas? 
Here's my code

```
$(".cc_submenu").find("ul.portfolio-list li").each(function(i){
    i == 4;
    $(this).addClass("cc_content_"+i);
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).find("a").attr("href","#");
    $('.cc_content .cc_content_'+i).load(href);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `i == 4` which is an equality operator, not an assignment. Just change it to `i += 4`;

```
$(".cc_submenu").find("ul.portfolio-list li").each(function(i){
    //i == 4; // This part will just return true/false, not change i
    i += 4; // this is what you're looking for.
    $(this).addClass("cc_content_"+i);
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).find("a").attr("href","#");
    $('.cc_content .cc_content_'+i).load(href);
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `+=1` instead of `+=4` -- and you need to define `i=4` somewhere before the `find()` function.

Comment: No, that i is being passed as an argument to the function representing the index. When you add 4 within the function it only affects that function scope. You need i to be 4 higher than its index, so i += 4, or i = i + 4;

Comment: @slhck: No, he means `+=4` if the first one is to start at `4`. jQuery passes the index into the iterator function, and the first index is `0`.

Comment: @T.J. See the answer of @Evan Mulawski - that's what I meant.

Comment: @slhck: He's incrementing a value that isn't being passed as an argument, so he's doing something completely different.

Comment: @Robert Yes, but he wanted the classes to start from number 4 and then go 5, 6, 7. As far as I read your code it goes 4, 8, 12, etc.

Comment: @slhck: @Robert is making use of the index variable that jQuery passes into `each` (details: http://api.jquery.com/each/). *"As far as I read your code it goes 4, 8, 12, etc."* You're misreading the code. The `i` is passed in by jQuery, then Robert is making a local, *temporary* change to it. Initially, jQuery will pass in `0`, then Robert will add `4` to it. On the next loop, jQuery will *pass in the value `1`* and Robert will add `4` to it. The local change to `i` disappears at the end of each iteration.

Comment: @slhck: You're not understanding where i is coming from. It only exists in the scope of that one function call, so it's 0, then 1, then 2, regardless of how I change it in each function, the next function is the index in the Array.

Comment: @Robert @T.J. Ah, now I see it. Sorry for that, I was mixing up the code in my head where i would have been declared before and `index` would not have been specified.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you are using the equality operator instead of assignment (`==` instead of `=`). Second, you could setup a variable outside the `each` iteration function and then increment the variable by one:

```
var i = 4;
$(".cc_submenu").find("ul.portfolio-list li").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("cc_content_"+i);
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).find("a").attr("href","#");
    $('.cc_content .cc_content_'+i).load(href);
    i += 1;
});
```

As a note:

`i == 4;` - this expression reports either true or false, but the return value is not stored anywhere. This isn't needed for your code.

`i = 4;`  - this expression sets `i` to `4`.

Comment: *"Second, you need to setup a variable outside the each iteration function and then increment the variable by one."* Or he can use the one *already provided* by the `each` function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I am aware of that, but the `each` function starts at zero. There is no way around that.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: There's nothing wrong with it starting at 0... you just increment it to what you want... if you wanted to start at 5, you add 5 to whatever value it passes to you.

Comment: @Robert: You are correct. However, I chose the snippet that would be more "readable" to the OP.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: Either way technically works, and that's fine, just trying to make sure there isn't any confusion. I'd prefer using arguments that are already being passed to me whether I use them or not.

Comment: @Robert: I do prefer your way over mine, it achieves the desired result with minimal changes. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cc_submenu").find("ul.portfolio-list li:gt(3)").each(function(i,value){
    $(this).addClass("cc_content_"+i);
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).find("a").attr("href","#");
    $('.cc_content .cc_content_'+i).load(href);
});
```